# consecutive grouped weighted avereages and sums in a trade log

Tags: google-sheets, logic, weighted-average

I am trying to construct a trading tracker and want to be able to bunch like trades in chronological batches for calculation. So in the example below, I have a series of buy orders  with various prices and amounts, then followed by sell orders with similar info, and alternating between buying and selling.

I want to automatically bunch consecutive sets of buy/sell orders and create a weighted average, and other calculations on them
What is important that is to catch all sell or buy orders that are chronologically groupings.

I am looking for how to set up a logic test to bunch these consecutive buy/sell orders so I can do calculations on them (e.g. reduce them to a single trade price and amount per bunch of buys and sells.

The table is being populated from a form so this table should operate somewhat on autopilot. Here I have done a manual calculation on sample data to show what I am trying to achieve.

[image: sample data]

Answer (score 1):

`QUERY` does not support the weighted average which means you can't have one cell `ARRAYFORMULA`

so here is the dragging solution:

### `AVERAGE.WEIGHTED`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(
 INDIRECT("B"&ROW()&":B"&MATCH(INDEX(
 {IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(IF(A$2:A="",,ROW(A$2:A))))=
     INDIRECT("A1:A"&MAX(IF(A$2:A="",,ROW(A$2:A)))-1),, 1); 1}, 
 ROW()-(ROW(A$2)-1)), QUERY(
 {IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(IF(A$2:A="",,ROW(A$2:A))))=
     INDIRECT("A1:A"&MAX(IF(A$2:A="",,ROW(A$2:A)))-1),, 1); 1}, 
 "offset "&ROW()-1), 0)+ROW()-1),
 INDIRECT("C"&ROW()&":C"&MATCH(INDEX(
 {IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(IF(A$2:A="",,ROW(A$2:A))))=
     INDIRECT("A1:A"&MAX(IF(A$2:A="",,ROW(A$2:A)))-1),, 1); 1}, 
 ROW()-(ROW(A$2)-1)), QUERY(
 {IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(IF(A$2:A="",,ROW(A$2:A))))=
     INDIRECT("A1:A"&MAX(IF(A$2:A="",,ROW(A$2:A)))-1),, 1); 1}, 
 "offset "&ROW()-1), 0)+ROW()-1))))
```

[image]

### `SUM`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(SUM(
 INDIRECT("C"&ROW()&":C"&MATCH(INDEX(
 {IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(IF(A$2:A="",,ROW(A$2:A))))=
     INDIRECT("A1:A"&MAX(IF(A$2:A="",,ROW(A$2:A)))-1),, 1); 1}, 
 ROW()-(ROW(A$2)-1)), QUERY(
 {IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(IF(A$2:A="",,ROW(A$2:A))))=
     INDIRECT("A1:A"&MAX(IF(A$2:A="",,ROW(A$2:A)))-1),, 1); 1}, 
 "offset "&ROW()-1), 0)+ROW()-1))))
```

[image]

---

both of them are row independent so you may use them in script automation instead of dragging it manually:

see: **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCBtsQGtzoQ**

Comment: that is some next level cell formula.
I am dissecting it in order to apply it to my more complex data set.

Many thanks for your effort with this